# Difference between recite /read/tell a poem

Tags: difference

What should I say to my child?

> Mama, tell/recite/read any poem which you remember or learn.

Please, tell me here which word is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

"Read a poem" means that you are reading it from a book or other printed text.

"Recite a poem" means that you are quoting it, verbatim, without the need for a text.

"Tell" doesn't sound idiomatic in this context at all. "Telling" something normally means that you are speaking extemporaneously, but with poetry, you should stick to the intended words. "Tell a *story*" is appropriate because a story does not rely on a rhyme scheme or rhythm and so the same content can be told extemporaneously.

"Recite" would, therefore, be the most appropriate word for your sentence, although it does sound a little formal given the context:

> Recite any poem that you have learned.

Some English speakers might use the expression "*say* a poem", especially the kind of poems a child might learn, such as "nursery rhymes". Some even say "*sing* a nursery rhyme", regardless of whether the rhyme is set to music or not.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=say%20a%20poem%2C%20recite%20a%20poem%2C%20tell%20a%20poem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csay%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecite%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctell%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csay%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecite%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctell%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0) shows that "recite" is mostly used for speaking poems.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=say%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%2Crecite%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%2C%20sing%20a%20nursery%20rhyme&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csay%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecite%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csing%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csay%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecite%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csing%20a%20nursery%20rhyme%3B%2Cc0) shows that "recite" is also most widely used with "nursery rhymes", but also that "sing" and "say" are used almost as frequently as one another.

Answer (score 0):

[Recite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recite) - to repeat from memory or read aloud publicly

Recite is used when you are performing something, such as a poetry reading or a dance.

You ask what you'd say to a child, but unless you're calling your child Mama, this is something your child would say to you.

> Mama, **recite** me a poem you remember or **learned**.